# What are the Net.ton.dev Endpoints?

Tags: solidity, everscale

What are the standard endpoints for "net.ton.dev" are working?
Through tonos-cli, for instance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's on their docs, here you can see the current endpoints: https://docs.everos.dev/evernode-platform/products/evercloud/networks-endpoints